# Test coverage for the "Continue" function

Tags: unit-test

I have a trigger that I only have 92% test coverage for and when I review the lines not covered using the Developer Console, it is only the two lines "continue;". How do I incorporate these into my test class so I can get the highest coverage possible?

Trigger

```
trigger SetPrimaryCampaign on Opportunity (after insert) {                   

     // Make a List of Opps and Contact ID's.                        
    List<Id> oppIds = new List<Id>();
    List<Id> contIds = new List<Id>();                    

    for( Opportunity o : Trigger.new ) {                    
        if(o.Sourced_by__c <> null)  {                  
             // If it is determined this should fire on update too. You will want the line below to ensure this does not fire on every update only when the Sourced_by__c value changes                    
             // && (Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).Sourced_by__c != opp.Sourced_by__c ) )                   
                oppIds.add( o.Id ); 
                contIds.add( o.Sourced_by__c );                 
                continue;                   
        }                   
    }                   

    Map<Id,Opportunity> oppMap = new Map<Id,Opportunity>( [SELECT Id, Sourced_by__c from Opportunity where Id IN :oppIds] );                    
    Map<Id, CampaignMember> campMap = new Map<Id, CampaignMember>([Select id, ContactId, CampaignId, CreatedDate From CampaignMember where ContactId IN : contIds]);                 

    List<Opportunity> opps = new List<Opportunity>();                   
        for( Opportunity opp : oppMap.values() ) {              
            Opportunity op = new Opportunity();         

                CampaignMember oldestCM; //Carries the ID of the oldest CampaignMember by CreatedDate       
                Datetime oldestdate; //Holds the date for the oldestCM value that is checked        

                for(CampaignMember cammem : campMap.values() ) {        
                    if((cammem.CreatedDate <= oldestdate || oldestdate == null) && cammem.ContactId == opp.Sourced_by__c){  
                        oldestCM = cammem;
                        oldestdate = cammem.CreatedDate;
                    }   
                    else{   
                        continue;
                    }   
                }       
                    if(oldestCM <> null){   
                        op.id = opp.id;
                        op.CampaignId = oldestCM.campaignId;
                        opps.add(op);
                    }   
                    else{   
                        continue;
                    }   
        }               
        update opps;                    
    }
```

Test Class

```
@IsTest (SeeAllData=true) private class VennSci_TEST_SetPrimaryCampaign{

    private static testMethod void myUnitTest() {

// create an Account
Account acc=new Account(Name='test');
insert acc;                

 // create a Contact
        Contact cont = new Contact(
        Firstname='Jane',
        Lastname='Doe',
        AccountID= acc.Id

    );
    insert cont;

       // create the 1st Campaign
    Campaign c1 = new Campaign(
        name='Campaign 1',
        IsActive=true,
        StartDate=Date.newInstance(2013,01,01)
        );
    insert c1;

   // create the 2nd Campaign
    Campaign c2 = new Campaign(
        name='Campaign 2',
        IsActive=true,
        StartDate=Date.newInstance(2014,01,01)
        );
    insert c2;

    // create the ist Campaign Member
    Campaignmember cm1 = new CampaignMember(
        CampaignId=c1.Id,
        ContactID=cont.Id,
        Status='Sent'
             );
    insert cm1;

   // create the 2nd Campaign Member
    CampaignMember cm2 = new CampaignMember(
        CampaignId=c2.Id,
        ContactId=cont.Id,
        Status='Sent'
                );
    insert cm2;


    // create the opportunity positive
        Opportunity opp1 = new Opportunity(
        name='Test Opp 1',
        StageName = 'Closed Won',
        CloseDate = Date.newInstance(2014,01,01),
        Sourced_By__c = cont.Id 

    );
    insert opp1;


    // create the opportunity negative
        Opportunity opp2 = new Opportunity(
        name='Test Opp 2',
        StageName = 'Closed Won',
        CloseDate = Date.newInstance(2014,01,01)

    );
    insert opp2;


   }
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove both of the `continue;` lines from your code. They serve no real purpose because there is no following code to [skip over](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_loops.htm). The same would apply to the 2nd `else` statement.